# Using GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT when joining values from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that pulls all orders for an order:

```
SELECT 
   order_id, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(order_item_name SEPARATOR ' | ') as 'items' 
FROM 
   wp_woocommerce_order_items oi1 
WHERE 
   oi1.order_item_type = 'line_item' 
   AND order_id = 422 
GROUP BY
   order_id
```

It returns my desired results:

[image]

What I'd like to do now is to add data from another table that looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta where order_item_id = 17`

`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` and `wp_woocommerce_order_items` join on `order_item_id`

[image]

So my final desired results would look something like:

```
order_item_name:_qty:_line_subtotal

order_id | items
--------- -----------------------------------
422      | Metal Polish:1:13.09
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each value in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` is in its own row, you'll need to join that table multiple times.

```
SELECT order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(
   order_item_name,':',qty.meta_value,':',subtotal.meta_value SEPARATOR ' | '
) as 'items' 

FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items oi1

JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta qty ON
    qty.order_item_id = oli.order_item_id
    AND qty.meta_key = '_qty'
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta subtotal ON
    qty.order_item_id = oli.order_item_id
    AND qty.meta_key = '_line_subtotal'

WHERE oi1.order_item_type = 'line_item' 
   AND order_id = 422 
GROUP BY order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need some like this?

```
SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as wc 
inner join
(SELECT 
   order_id, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(order_item_name SEPARATOR ' | ') as 'items' 
FROM 
   wp_woocommerce_order_items oi1 
WHERE 
   oi1.order_item_type = 'line_item' 
   AND order_id = 422 
GROUP BY
   order_id) as order_counts
using (order_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample only with one LEFT JOIN and a CONCAT

```
SELECT 
   oi1.order_id, 
   GROUP_CONCAT( 
     CONCAT(oi1.order_item_name , ':', ii.meta_value)
     SEPARATOR ' | ') as 'items' 
FROM 
   wp_woocommerce_order_items oi1 
LEFT JOIN
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta i ON i.order_item_id = oi1.order_item_id AND i.meta_key= '_line_subtotal'
WHERE 
   oi1.order_item_type = 'line_item' 
   AND oi1.order_id = 422 
GROUP BY
   oi1.order_id;
```